# How to set value of textbox created in code behind in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I'm creating a textbox in the code behind:

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "txtRef" + count + dr["DataField"].ToString();
div.Controls.Add(txt);
```

And I'm trying to set the value for this textbox in a jquery function but nothing I have tried so far is updating the textbox.

Using `document.getElementById('txtRef1j.3rdPartRef').value = 'test';` returns the error Cannot set property 'value' of null.

I also tried `$('#txtRef1j.3rdPartRef').val('test')` and `$('[id$="txtRef1j.3rdPartRef"]').value = 'test';` but the textbox doesn't update.

Comment: Have you checked the id of textbox?

Comment: @Lalit Yes ID in the code behind is `txtRef1j.3rdPartRef`. If I check the console for the ID its `id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRef1j.3rdPartRef"`. I have also tried using this ID but it still won't update the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it: `$('[id$="txtRef1j.3rdPartRef"]')[0].value  = 'test';` 
or `document.getElementById('txtRef1j.3rdPartRef')[0].value = 'test';` or 
`$('[id$="txtRef1j.3rdPartRef"]').get(0).value  = 'test';`  or

```
    document.querySelector('[id$="txtRef1j.3rdPartRef').value = 'test'
```

or

```
$('[id$="txtRef1j.3rdPartRef"]').val('test');`
```

You have errors because jquery object don't has property `value`,only Dom element has proerty `value` . When you use document.getElementById,  you get NodeList , it is not a Dom-Element. You can read:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: $('[id$="txtRef1j.3rdPartRef"]')[0].value = 'test'; worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

$('#txtRef1j.3rdPartRef').text('test')

Comment: Hey, it seems this doesn't work as to solve OPs question however for future answers try to include some reference material or a description of what the code done.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the textbox name you set is same in the HTML DOM. Right click the textbox and see the ID by inspect element. If it is not same as you built in c#, then add a line of code `txt.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;` The ID will not be same as it generates dynamic textbox ID.

If the ID is same and still if not working, then run the given jquery and javascript statements in browser console and try they are working or not.

F12, goto console, paste `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRef1j.3rdPartRef").val('test');` and press enter. If the value is getting set, then its because of dynamic ID. just add the client id mode as static and it will work.